# Angular :host <selector> is not working

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-components

I want to style my component  if it has a class **active**. But it doesn't work.

**thread.component.html**

```
<div>thread works!</div>
```

**thread.component.css**

```
:host .active {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-thread class="active"></app-thread>
```

---

However, if I remove active class in app.comonent.html file and thread.component.css. **It works perfectly fine.**

**thread.component.html**

```
<div>thread works!</div>
```

**thread.component.css**

```
:host {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-thread></app-thread>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors):

> Use the :host pseudo-class selector to target styles in the element
> that hosts the component (as opposed to targeting elements inside the
> component's template).

So

```
:host {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

will set the style for the whole host, so your element will just inherit of that style.

But here you are targetting a class `.active` inside `:host`:

```
// Any element with class "active", that is inside :host .
// Same as ":host *.active".
:host .active {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Do instead:

```
// :host when it has the class "active".
:host(.active) {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

**And be careful to NOT set**

```
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

in the component code

Comment: Note there must be a space after `:host` (before the curly bracket) otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 25):

`:host` will not take effect if you have `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component's definition as shown below.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Solution in this situation => https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091232/2736742

Comment: There's a case where if you style the component by its tag in the parent component; it overrides the child's :host even if its encapsulation is emulated.

Answer (score 1):

:host is used to add styling **to the component as such and not to the elements inside it.**

```
:host
{
   background-color: red;
}
```

applies a red background to the angular component as a whole.

Now :host(.active) is used to add styling to the component only when the component has an active class on it.

Comment: Due to some reason, this is not working on my project which developed using Angular version 9. Is there anything that I have to do rather than adding that `:host` part to the component styling file?

Comment: What's your component's view enscapulation?